# Need to run a powershell script every time system wakes up from Sleep

Tags: powershell, sleep, wakeup

I just finished writing a script with PowerShell and I need it to run every time my system wakes up from sleep or Hibernation. 
I tried the gpedit.msc -> User Config -> Windows Settings -> Scripts -> Logon but this does not work when my system Wakes up from 'Sleep'... probably because 'Sleep' - > 'Wake -up' is not technically new logon (As a user I am already logged-on).

Either a Sleep-Wake event or Login (User Login) event should trigger my script.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

More Info on what my script does: It checks if internet/network is connected. If yes, it will attempt to run the Cisco VPN connection command line utility with required arguments and logs me into VPN. Every time I wake my system up from sleep and login I need the damn VPN to connect me automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. I used the Task Scheduler as Richard indicated above.

I set the Trigger as..
On an Event -> System -> Kernel-Power -> 42

If anyone is interested... here is the script (I am a beginner with PowerShell scripts, so welcome your inputs)

```
$strComputerName = gc env:computername
$strVPN = 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\vpnclient.exe'
$vpnArgs = 'connect', 'ProfileName', 'user', 'XXXXXXXX', 'pwd', 'XXXXXXXXXX'
[int]$count = 6
Write-Host "Checking for Internet Connectivity"
While (!([Activator]::CreateInstance([Type]::GetTypeFromCLSID([Guid]'{DCB00C01-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B}')).IsConnectedToInternet))
{
    Write-Host "Sleeping for 10 seconds before checking for internet again"
    Start-Sleep -s 10
    $count--
    if ( $count -eq 0) 
    {
        Write-Host "Breaking from loop"
        break
    }
}
if ( $count -ne 0) { Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { & $strVPN $vpnArgs } }
else { Write-Host "No Internet Connectivity, so not attempting VPN connection" }
```

Comment: This worked for me but to get the Event ID you can check the Event Viewer > System and look for Kernel-Power events in the Source column and find the one that says it's for wake up. For me the Event ID was 107 (42 was the go to sleep event).

I cleared my log, used sleep, and woke it up to get a very short list to look through.

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this by scheduling a task to run the script, triggering on event "Power-Troubleshooter" with Event ID *1*. This is the event that's logged by the system when it **resumes** from sleep. When the system is **entering** sleep, the "Kernel-Power" event is called with Event ID *42* (unlike what another answer here suggests).

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Task Scheduler would seem to be a better fit.

If a task trigger of "At Startup" doesn't work in this case (I suspect it won't) then identify an event log entry posted on wake from sleep and trigger on that.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11 the Event Id we can use for this is 566

I set the Trigger as> On an Event -> System -> Kernel-Power -> 566

Here is my configuration
[Scheduled task triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5dcO.png)

In my case I run a powershell script that turns on my keyboard backlight on my laptop. The backlight now turns on after windows has resumed from sleep (open the lid on laptop) but before I have logged in.

You also might want to uncheck: conditions > Power > "start the task only if the computer is on AC power"

Comment: I found 566 to work the best, but sometimes it gets triggered again right after the system resumes, resulting in my sleep script running when it shouldn't.

Comment: For me the Event ID was 107, also on W11 (see my comment in the accepted answer)